# Filtering items displayed in TableView with checked items in SideMenu in Swift

Tags: swift, tableview, filtering, items

I am planning an app which is listing calendar-items in a tableview. I would also like to implement a sidemenu where the different calendars can be checked to show or hide their events.

As I am very new to swift I tried to find a solution to my problem but couldn´t find any so far.

There is probably allready information about it available somewhere but I don´t know what to look for.

Answer (score -1):

For this i would suggest UITableView with hamburger menu, documented here: http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/

Or you can make another controller with UITableView for choosing the calendars and show/hide by native iOS model presentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html

Or if your app will be iPad only you can try splitViewController https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html

Hope this helps